# How to show Actionsheet in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uialertcontroller

How can I show a `UIActionsheet` in iPad when I'm using my current code its giving me this error:

> Your application has presented a `UIAlertController` (`<UIAlertController: 0x7f9ec624af70>`) of style `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`. The `modalPresentationStyle` of a `UIAlertController` with this style is `UIModalPresentationPopover`. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's `popoverPresentationController`. You must provide either a `sourceView` and `sourceRect` or a `barButtonItem`.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` method `-prepareForPopoverPresentation`.

which is working totally fine in an iPhone :

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
let reminderAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Reminder", style: .Default, handler: {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in }
optionMenu.addAction(reminderAction)
self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I came across some similar problems, the solution was this:

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
```

but it didnt worked for me maybe because my ActionSheet's Sender is on a UItableviewCell.

I tired to set AlertController's Sourceview  to tableView's Cell but its not correctly placed and sometime its partially visible this is what I tried:

```
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = currentCell.contentView
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = currentCell.contentView.bounds
```

Any clue how can I fix this problem?

Comment: So the problem is that you cant position properly your popover controller?

Comment: yes @roher , its not proper and also AlertView is flashing while interacting to it

Answer (score 14):

The sample code given below works both on iPhone and iPad.

```
 guard let viewRect = sender as? UIView else {
            return
        }

    let cameraSettingsAlert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Please choose a course", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    cameraSettingsAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

    let photoResolutionAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Photo Resolution", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    }
    let cameraOrientationAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Camera Orientation", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    }
    let flashModeAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Flash Mode", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    }
    let timeStampOnPhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Time Stamp on Photo", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .Cancel) { action in

    }
    cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(cancel)
    cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(cameraOrientationAction)
    cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(flashModeAction)
    cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(timeStampOnPhotoAction)
    cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(photoResolutionAction)

    if let presenter = cameraSettingsAlert.popoverPresentationController {
        presenter.sourceView = viewRect;
        presenter.sourceRect = viewRect.bounds;
    }
    presentViewController(cameraSettingsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: can't we set this View (the ActivityView) to centre of Current Window  (screen) because here my sender is a UIView (which disappears once tap on it  to open this activityView)

Comment: Seems to me that the key is this bit of code: presenter.sourceView = viewRect; presenter.sourceRect = viewRect.bounds;

Answer (score 7):

If you want to show any ActionSheet on iPad so their use popoverPresentationController to show and at iPad don't show the cancel style button of action sheet.
Use this code in Swift 3:

```
  @IBAction func ActionSheetShow(_ sender: UIButton) {

  let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose any option", message: "choose as you like here!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click1", style: .cancel, handler: {
    action in
        print("first button")
    }))
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click2", style: .default, handler: {
        action in
        print("second button")
    }))
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click3", style: .destructive, handler: {
        action in
        print("third button")
    }))
    actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.1 Solution:-**

> 1. MAK Eextension FILE UIDEviceExtension.swift and with below code  :-

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
public extension UIDevice {

    public class var isPhone: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    }

    public class var isPad: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    }

    public class var isTV: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .tv
    }

    public class var isCarPlay: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .carPlay
    }

}
```

> 2. Call your action Sheet on UIViewcontroller By this Separate common method :-

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class Common: NSObject{
       public class func showActionSheet(vc: UIViewController,sender:UIButton? = nil) {

                let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

                actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    //self.camera()
                }))

                actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    //self.photoLibrary()
                }))

                actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

                //if iPhone
                if UIDevice.isPhone {
                    vc.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    //In iPad Change Rect to position Popover
                    if let btn = sender{
                        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = btn.frame
                        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = vc.view

                    }
                    vc.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }
    }
```

> 3. Use it from your UIButton Click for iPhone/iPad both :-

```
   @objc func btnPicImageTaped(btn:UIButton){
        print("it will work for both iPhone /ipad")
        Common.showActionSheet(vc: self,sender: btn)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Following two lines before presentViewController. (**Swift 3.2**)

```
 optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
 optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).frame
 present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take sourceView & sourceRect from sender:

```
@IBAction func btMenuPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let Sender = sender as? UIButton
    let actSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    actSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "settings", style: .default) { _ in self.doSettings() })
    ...
    ...
    actSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = Sender!.superview!    
    actSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = Sender!.frame
    resent(actSheet, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: works well, just need to fix the resent typo on the last line to present ;)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+ solution Very smooth and easy just call this function and you will easy solve your problem

```
let IPAD = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad


//Mark:- Choose Action Sheet Methods
func actionSheet() {
    var actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)

    actionSheet.view.tintColor = UIColor.black

    let button1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Button 1".localizableString(language: Defaults.selectedLanguageCode), style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    })
    let button2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Button 2".localizableString(language: Defaults.selectedLanguageCode), style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localizableString(language: Defaults.selectedLanguageCode), style: .cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    })


    if IPAD {
        //In iPad Change Rect to position Popover
        actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(button1)
    actionSheet.addAction(button2)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
    print("Action Sheet Open")

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated for swift 5

```
extension UIDevice {

    class var isPhone: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    }

     class var isPad: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    }

     class var isTV: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .tv
    }

     class var isCarPlay: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .carPlay
    }

}
```